# How to receive DTMF receive during call in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am new in linphone. Anyone can guide me how to receive dtmf during call in 
iOS. I puted method this in **LinphoneCoreVTable**.

`.dtmf_received = linphone_iphone_notify_dtmf_received.`

But when this method call I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement function which get called when dtmf is received.

Interface of function is following:

```
/**
 * Callback for being notified of DTMFs received.
 * @param lc the linphone core
 * @param call the call that received the dtmf
 * @param dtmf the ascii code of the dtmf
 */
typedef void (*LinphoneCoreCbsDtmfReceivedCb)(LinphoneCore* lc, LinphoneCall *call, int dtmf);
```

Is a same as for call state change:

VTable

```
.call_state_changed = (LinphoneCoreCallStateChangedCb)linphone_iphone_call_state,
```

Interface

```
/**
 * Call state notification callback.
 * @param lc the LinphoneCore
 * @param call the call object whose state is changed.
 * @param cstate the new state of the call
 * @param message a non NULL informational message about the state.
 */
typedef void (*LinphoneCoreCbsCallStateChangedCb)(LinphoneCore *lc, LinphoneCall *call, LinphoneCallState cstate, const char *message);
```

And method

```
static void linphone_iphone_call_state(LinphoneCore *lc, LinphoneCall *call, LinphoneCallState state, const char *message) {
    [(__bridge LinphoneManager *)linphone_core_get_user_data(lc) onCall:call StateChanged:state withMessage:message];
}
```